# Is there any easy way to find a quest destination ?

Tags: diablo-iii

The map doesn't always help me find my destination and I sometimes end up wandering. 
Is there something I'm missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're extremely distant from the objective, the Waypoint system will indicate the closest node with a yellow chalice icon.  When closer, you can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to pull up the map overlay and drag it around to find a direction/destination.

Answer (score 1):

Once you approach the general area of the quest destination, a blue arrow will appear on your minimap pointing the way.